# If $(a-b) \int_{0}^{a} \int_{0}^{b}f(x,y)dydx = (a-b/2)\int_{0}^{a} \int_{0}^{b/2}f(x,y)dydx$, is there a way to find $f(x,y)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If 
$$(a-b) \int_{0}^{a} \int_{0}^{x+c}f(x,y)\,dydx = \left(a-\frac{b}{2}\right)\int_{0}^{a} \int_{0}^{x+c/2}f(x,y)\,dydx,$$ is there a way to find $f(x,y)$?

The followings hold: $f(x,y) \neq g(x) h(y)$. $F(x,y)$, which is CDF of $f(x,y)$, is continuous. Support of $x$ is $(0,r)$ and that of $y$ is $(0,2r)$. Also $(a < r)$ and $(b < 2r)$. And $c>0$ is some constant, such that $r+c < 2r$.

Answer (score 0):

One attempt could be to divide by $a−b$ and to take the derivative on both sides:
$$LHS = f(a,b),\quad RHS = \frac{1}{4}f(a,b/2).$$
Maybe this already helps. Without any further properties on $f$ there is more than one solution to your equation. E.g. take $f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$. Then, you have no relation for $g$ as the corresponding terms on the left- and right-hand side cancel.

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestion.  The guy who edited my question "did not edit it properly," because of the fraction in the brackets on the RHS was not correct after editing.  Now, the above equation is a correct one.

Comment: One more thing: I know for sure that the distribution of variables $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, but I dont know $f(x,y)$. Thus, I wish to find such joint distribution that satisfies the above equality

Answer (score 0):

There will not exist any such probability distribution $f$. Just consider $b=2a$. Then the right-hand side vanishes while the left-hand side equals
$$0=−a\int_0^a\int_0^{2a}f(x,y)\,dy\,dx.$$
As $f$ is non-negative, we must have $f=0$ on $(0,r)\times (0,2r)$, which is a contradiction.

You could also use $a=r$ and $b=2r$ to conclude that $RHS=0=LHS=\int f=1$, which again is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks a  lot! You are absolutely right.  My apologies -- while making the simplification of the original equation, I omitted another important info.  I made necessary corrections in the original question.